# Why does my 2 byte variable in assembler (x86) not get intialized properly?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

I am working currently on x86 (8086 cpu) with assembler.

My data segment looks like this:

```
DATOS SEGMENT   
TOME        DW  0CAFEH
DATOS ENDS
```

however when I look at the adress using turbo debugger, only CA shows up but FE doesn't

The data segment gets initialized properly

pls help xd

[this is how my memory looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikwsk.png)

Comment: How did you "look" at it? Especially in an assembler ... maybe you mean debugger?

Comment: Agreed - probably when you are "looking" at it, you are only looking at the immediate 16 bits at the address, not the entire 32 bit dataword as described. You can verify by "looking" at tome plus an offset and see if the second half of the word is there?

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: Your stack overlaps the `DATOS` segment.

Comment: @uint64_t: What 32-bit doubleword?  DW *is* one data word, which is 16-bit in x86 terminology.  (Word = 16-bit was established with 8086, and Intel didn't confuse everyone by changing the meaning of a size.  Which would have been insane because instructions like `cbw` (sign-extend byte to word) were already part of the ISA.)